# How to post data with HttpResponseRedirect in Django?

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates, django-views

How to post data with HttpResponseRedirect?

I have a button in Django admin change form:

```
<input type="submit" value="Test Peer" name="_peer-test">
```

and the view to get it:

```
def response_change(self, request, obj): ### response
    if "_peer-test" in request.POST:  
          url = request.POST.get('obj', '/export')
          return HttpResponseRedirect(url)
```

The first line def response_change(self, request, obj): has data

So if I type obj.name I will get the requested data.

What I want is to redirect to another view en post de information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get your data from POST and send it as GET parametrs. See

```
def response_change(self, request, obj): ### response
    if "_peer-test" in request.POST:  
          url = request.POST.get('obj', '/export')
          if url != '/export':
              # because "obj" in variable url
              name = url.name
              url += "?name={}".format(name)
          return HttpResponseRedirect(url)
```

Thus you can get this value in view that need to recieve it. Example:

```
def reciever_view(request):
    name = request.GET.get('name','')
    # do some with name ...
```

Comment: It Worked! thank you! how can i get all the object in one time? so I don't have to define the objects one by one